# Changing a Cloud DNS IP (Resource Record Type A) with no propagation time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, istio, forwarding, google-cloud-dns

I have a GKE Cluster with istio installed. Istio ingress gateway automatically creates a load balancer with an IP.

I put this IP in Cloud DNS as image below (Fake IP with hidden DNS name). Everything work and I can access my cluster using the URL.

[image]

I know I can reduce TTL time to try reduce propagation time if I need to change the IP as described in documentation.

> **Propagation of changes**
>
> Changes are propagated in two parts. First, the change that you send
>   through the API or command-line tool must be pushed to Cloud DNS's
>   authoritative DNS servers. Second, DNS resolvers must pick up this
>   change when their cache of the records expires.
>
> The DNS resolver's cache is controlled by the time-to-live (TTL) value
>   that you set for your records, which is specified in seconds. For
>   example, if you set a TTL value of 86400 (the number of seconds in 24
>   hours), the DNS resolvers are instructed to cache the records for 24
>   hours. Some DNS resolvers ignore the TTL value or use their own values
>   that can delay the full propagation of records.
>
> If you are planning for a change to services that requires a narrow
>   window, you might want to change the TTL to a shorter value prior to
>   making your change. This approach can help reduce the caching window
>   and ensure a quicker change to your new record settings. After the
>   change, you can change the value back to its previous TTL value to
>   reduce load on the DNS resolvers.

But as you can see this solution is not reliable because some DNS resolvers can not follow my TTL.
Is there any way to reduce this propagation time to zero? I tried to create a load balancer and a forwarding rule with no success.

Comment: No - that is not the way DNS caching works. You have no control over the amount of time other DNS caches retain values. The TTL is a suggestion and not a mandatory value that must be respected. Another item, you do not want short TTL times. That slows down the Internet as each DNS query takes time. This causes delays mapping DNS names to IP addresses and increases your DNS server costs.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But is there any way to eliminate propagation time? Maybe a load balancer pointing to Istio ingress gateway load balancing? I would use LB IP instead of ingress gateway IP. This way if ingress gateway IP changes I would change LB backend and not Cloud DNS IPV4 address.. I tried that but with no success.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. In any event, changing IP addresses is not an instant process. Global resources such as load balancers take time to update globally. Not much time for your use case but you have no control over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can influence on propagation time is TTL values for your zone, 
so feel free to set TTL for your zone as minimum as allowed by Google Cloud DNS. But keep in mind that you're not able to force all the DNS servers over the Internet to propagate changes as quick as you'd like to, because a lot of them  configured to override the TTL settings you specified as it described [here](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/giovane_moura/dns-ttl-violations-in-the-wild-with-ripe-atlas-2).

As possible solution, you can try to reserve static IP addresses and set DNS records in advance as it described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke#creating_a_kubernetes_ingress_object) if it applicable for your use case.